# Is the barplot in matplotlib using the mean?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset `df`:

```
users  number   
user1   1          
user2   34       
user3   56      
user4   45      
user5   4
user1   3
user5   11
user1   3
```

when making a barplot like this:

```
plt.bar(x['users'], x['number'].sort_values(ascending=False), color="blue")
```

Does it take the mean of every `user` in the `number` column during the plot?
What if I want the sum of all the numbers in the `number` column to appear in the barplot in descending order?

I tried this:

```
plt.bar(x['users'], x['number'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False), color="blue")
```

which gives:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'sort_values'
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [10,34,56,45,33],
'user': ['user1','user2','user3','user4','user1']})
#index=['user1','user2','user3','user4','user1'])
plt.bar(df['user'], df['number'], color="blue")
```

[image]

**It always keeps the biggest value for the user that has many values.**

Comment: `x['number'].sum()` is the sum of all the rows `=157`. Of course you can't apply sort on a single number

Comment: yes which is not the answer.Can you tell if it takes the mean when using barplot?

Comment: No, it will take **whatever you give it**. You are currently giving the y-axis to be the sum which is a single number. Check my answer below if that's what you want. If you want the mean, then you will first have to compute the mean and then use the bar plot

Comment: I was referring to the previous case before the sum. If you have many values for user1 and other and you make a barplot like this `plt.bar(x['users'], x['number'], color="blue") what is it gonna show for each user if they have many values and it shows one value for each. That's what I said

Comment: Then it will show what my answer plots below. What do you finally want to plot: average/mean for each user OR all the values in your dataframe like in my answer? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I want to make the sum as you did which is correct. What I want a clarification in  is what gets plot when you have many values (numbers) for many users and you just plot it. Which one of the many values per user is going to be plot.Get it?

Comment: It will plot all the values which means even if `user1` has 3 different values, they will be plotted as separate bars as you can see in my first answer.

Comment: I think this is because of the range and len you wrote. If you try this you will see what I mean: import pandas as pd
`df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [10,34,56,45,33], 'user': ['user1','user2','user3','user4','user1']})
#index=['user1','user2','user3','user4','user1'])
plt.bar(df['user'], df['number'], color="blue")`

Comment: This will give error because your `x` values are now strings. You have to specify discrete positions on your x axis where you want to put bars. That's why I used `range(len(x))` because that will give you x-positions as 0, 1, 2.... Later you can label those positions as strings but for bar plotting, you would need numbers. Check [this](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) link. x has to be a sequence of scalars

Comment: The code I gave you gives you error? It runs normally for me. The point was that even though the user1 has two values it only keeps one in the barplot. That's what you mean error?

Comment: No, error means it complaints `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'`. Can you post the resulting plot in your question?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Ok, I got it. Now here is the thing. For `user1` you have two values: 33 and 10. It plots both bars, one with height 33 and the other with height 10 at the same x-location which is 'user1' . The reason you see only one is because the bar with height 33 overlaps the bar with height 10. Or in other words, since they are plotted in the same color (blue), you just see the highest bar. But in principle, both bars are present at that location. So yes, it seems df.plot() by default recognises the x-axis values and plots multiple bars for a given x

Comment: Makes sense. Why did you get an error ?

Comment: My version was old. I switched to the new one. Check my edited answer to see what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want OR do you want to first `groupby` the values for each user and then plot the total numbers in descending order.

```
x = x.sort_values('number',ascending=False)
plt.bar(range(len(x['users'])), x['number'], color="blue")
plt.xticks(range(len(x['users'])), x['users'])
plt.ylabel('Numbers')
```

**Output**

[image]

If you want to plot the mean of each user, use the following code:

```
x1 = x.groupby('users').mean().reset_index()
plt.bar(range(len(x1)), x1['number'], color="blue")
plt.xticks(range(len(x1)), x1['users'])
plt.ylabel('Mean')
```

**Output**

[image]

**What if you don't sort or group by**: All bars are present but you don't see the different bars for same x-value because `alpha=1` by default. I used `alpha=0.2` to highlight my point. Now you see that at `user1` there are two bars behind each other.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [10,34,56,45,51], 'user': 'user1','user2','user3','user4','user1']})
plt.bar(df['user'], df['number'], color="blue", linewidth =2, edgecolor='black' , alpha = 0.2)
```

**Output**

[image]